# Sum of geometric and Poisson distribution

Tags: poisson-distribution

Suppose I have $X \sim \mathrm{Geom}(p)$ and $Y=\mathrm{Pois}(\lambda)$.
I want to create $Z = X + Y$, where the $X$ begins at $0$ rather than $1$.

Is this possible? Then I would calculate the mean and variance.

Comment: If you want _only_ the expectation and the variance, then the answer by paw88789 below is all you need.  Your way of phrasing the question leaves uncertainty about whether you want only that or something more.

Answer (score 2):

Are $X$ and $Y$ independent?

For any random variables, $E[X+Y]=E[X]+E[Y]$; and for any **independent** random variables, $\text{Var}(X+Y)=\text{Var}(X)+\text{Var}(Y)$

Comment: This gives only the expectation and the variance.  The question is vague, but one must suspect he wants something like the probability mass function.

Comment: @MichaelHardy: You may be right.  I don't see a particularly nice way of expressing such a result.  One would presumably be multiplying together various geometric and Poisson probabilities and adding up sums of these products.

Answer (score 0):

Something that I thought of to compute the pmf, then the expectation, is:
$Pr(X=k)= p(1-k)^{k}$
$Pr(Y=k)=\frac{\lambda^k e^{\lambda}}{k!}$

Then:
$Pr(Z=k)=p(1-p)^{k} \frac{\lambda^k e^{\lambda}}{k!}$

Finally, the expected value of $Z$ would be

$E[Z] = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}k  p(1-p)^k \frac{\lambda^k e^{\lambda}}{k!} $

$E[Z] = p \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}k (1-p)^k \frac{\lambda^k e^{\lambda}}{k!} $

Now we split into $k = 0$, and then remaining $k$:

$E[Z] = p\{0 \frac{\lbrack(1-p)\lambda\rbrack^0 e^{-\lambda}}{0!}\} + p\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\lbrack(1-p)\lambda\rbrack^k e^{-\lambda}}{(k-1)!}$

$E[Z] = p \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\lbrack(1-p)\lambda\rbrack^k e^{-\lambda}}{(k-1)!}$

$E[Z] = e^{-\lambda} p\lbrack(1-p)\lambda\rbrack  \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\lbrack(1-p)\lambda\rbrack^{k-1}}{(k-1)!}$

Let $j=k-1$

$E[Z] = e^{-\lambda} p\lbrack(1-p)\lambda\rbrack \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \frac{\lbrack(1-p)\lambda\rbrack^j e^{-\lambda}}{j!}$

$E[Z] = e^{-\lambda} p\lbrack(1-p)\lambda\rbrack e^{(1-p)\lambda}$

$E[Z] =  p\lbrack(1-p)\lambda\rbrack e^{-\lambda p}$

Then the variance is straightforward.

Thanks!